# Synology NAS with two chained routers

Tags: router, routing, nas, wireless-bridge, synology-diskstation

[image]

As seen in the picture above, I have two routers and a Synology NAS. The first router is provided by my ISP and also has wi-fi. The second one, my own, it connected to the first by cable. It also has wi-fi (different SSID). To it, i connected my NAS, also via cable.

What I want is to be able to access the NAS from both wi-fi networks, but not to be visible from outside these two. For external purposes, I think I will use Quickconnect, which seems to be working fine.

As suggested while reading documentation, I should put my router wireless extender mode and as such have only one network visible. I did this and i simply could not find the NAS using find.synology.com . Also, I am worried (maybe due to lack of knowledge) that by setting the router as a bridge it would use a wireless connection between routers and not the wired one.

Comment: It's ill-advised, nor recommended, to allow access to a LAN through any ISP's provided router, as ISPs retain remote access to their equipment, and, by default, the customer's LAN. Best solution is to remove the ISP's router and directly connect your router to the modem, however, if it's a modem/router combo, have the ISP disable the router portion on their end, allowing for your router to receive a WAN IP on it's WAN port.  By allowing access to your LAN from the ISP's router, your LAN is no longer private - all it takes is one employee to abuse such access, which has occurred before.

Comment: Having the ISP router be "dummy" is also in the works. But the question remains, how do i do what I want?

Comment: Without knowing both routers' make and model, there's no way for you to receive specific instructions, but why you're intent on doing this is baffling since you're essentially asking how to make the data on your LAN susceptible to a data breach.  You likely have private data on your NAS - why exactly would you want to expose that data to a potential security breach?

Comment: I have the ISP provided router in one corner of the house. The TV is connected to it. Then the other router is in the other corner of the house, so I can get good wi-fi there too. That is the place where the NAS is plugged into. Now for a specific use-case. How can I access files (movies/photos) from the NAS, them being connected to different wi-fi networks?